# Adding Text After Specific Line of File in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a txt (`ip.txt`) file that contains IP addresess. I group them under TCP and UDP. File excerpt is below:

```
#TCP
162.298.38.930
162.298.38.931
162.298.38.932
#UDP
162.298.38.930
162.298.38.931
162.298.38.932
```

I have a specific IP (`162.298.38.929`) to add both by bash script into this ip.txt under TCP and UDP lines so it should like this.

```
#TCP
162.298.38.929
162.298.38.930
162.298.38.931
162.298.38.932
#UDP
162.298.38.929
162.298.38.930
162.298.38.931
162.298.38.932
```

How can I achieve this in bash script? Line number is not usable for my case because #TCP and #UDP line number can change because I add lots of comments into the file. Bash Script should search and add the IP both under TCP and UDP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use GNU Sed's Append Action

Assuming both sections have `162.298.38.932`, and that you want to append the other IP address immediately below both entries, then the following sed script does the job.

```
sed '/162\.298\.38\.932/a\162.298.38.929' ip.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see IP is added appropriately in terminal but when I check the file it does not have the changes saved. Any idea please?

Comment: @NecNecco If you want to edit the file in-place, rather than redirecting output to another file, then just add the `--in-place` flag when you call GNU sed.

Comment: now works perfectly